# Granting Permission on Databases and Schemas

Tags: sql-server

I have a  Security permissions script i have inherited that i'd like to improve. The script grants permissions on the user databases and Schemas.
I'd like to improve the script by  iterating through all the schemas instead of hard coding the schemas like i did within the cursor. 
Any thought?

**

```
-- Assigning Permission to 'Domain\Development' at a DAtabase level 
DECLARE @command nvarchar(max), @usr sysname, @DB nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @loginName varchar(256)
SET @loginName ='Domain\Development'
DECLARE Devcur CURSOR FOR 
SELECT NAME FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id>4 AND NAME <>LOOKUP'
                                                   AND NAME  NOT LIKE  '%ReportServer%'
                                                   AND NAME NOT LIKE '%DBAdmin%'
                                                   AND NAME NOT LIKE '%DBA%'
                                                   AND state_desc='ONLINE' AND is_read_only=0
OPEN Dev
FETCH NEXT FROM Devcur INTO  @DB
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--Granting Access to User databases 
BEGIN
    SET @usr='['+@loginName+']'
    SELECT @command = 'Use ' + @DB + ';
    EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_datareader'',N'''+REPLACE(REPLACE(@usr, '[', ''), ']', '')+'''; 
    EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_ddladmin'',N'''+REPLACE(REPLACE(@usr, '[', ''), ']', '')+'''; 
    EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_datawriter'',N'''+REPLACE(REPLACE(@usr, '[', ''), ']', '')+'''; 
    EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_owner'',N'''+REPLACE(REPLACE(@usr, '[', ''), ']', '')+''';
    GRANT Showplan TO '+@usr+';
    GRANT EXECUTE TO '+@usr+';
    GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO '+@usr+';
    GRANT CONNECT TO '+@usr+';
    GRANT CREATE SCHEMA TO '+@usr+';
    GRANT DELETE TO  '+@usr+';
    GRANT INSERT TO  '+@usr+';
    GRANT UPDATE TO  '+@usr+';'

    PRINT @command
    Print '-----------------BUILD-----------------'
    Print @DB
--EXEC SP_executeSQL @command
END
--Access SOMER schema
SET @usr='['+@loginName+']'
SELECT @command = 'Use ' + @DB + ';
IF (select Count(*) from sys.schemas where name = ''SOMER'') >= 1
BEGIN
EXEC sp_droprolemember N''db_denydatawriter'', N''' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@usr, '[', ''), ']', '') + '''; 
    GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[SOMER] TO ' + @usr + ';
    GRANT DELETE ON SCHEMA::[SOMER] TO ' + @usr + ';
    GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA::[SOMER] TO ' + @usr + ';
    GRANT UPDATE ON SCHEMA::[SOMER] TO ' + @usr + ';
    GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[SOMER] TO ' + @usr + ';
End;'
--PRINT @command
EXEC SP_executeSQL @command
--Access Poser schema
SET @usr='['+@loginName+']'
SELECT @command = 'Use ' + @DB + ';
IF (select Count(*) from sys.schemas where name = ''Lser'') >= 1
BEGIN
EXEC sp_droprolemember N''db_denydatawriter'', N''' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@usr, '[', ''), ']', '') + '''; 
    GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[Lser] TO ' + @usr + ';
    GRANT DELETE ON SCHEMA::[Poser] TO ' + @usr + ';
    GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA::[Poser] TO ' + @usr + ';
    GRANT UPDATE ON SCHEMA::[Poser] TO ' + @usr + ';
    GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[Poser] TO ' + @usr + ';
End;'
--PRINT @command
EXEC SP_executeSQL @command
--Access Lser schema
SET @usr='['+@loginName+']'
SELECT @command = 'Use ' + @DB + ';
IF (select Count(*) from sys.schemas where name = ''Lser'') >= 1
BEGIN
EXEC sp_droprolemember N''db_denydatawriter'', N''' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@usr, '[', ''), ']', '') + '''; 
    GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[Lser] TO ' + @usr + ';
    GRANT DELETE ON SCHEMA::[Lser] TO ' + @usr + ';
    GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA::[Lser] TO ' + @usr + ';
    GRANT UPDATE ON SCHEMA::[Lser] TO ' + @usr + ';
    GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[Lser] TO ' + @usr + ';
End;'
--PRINT @command
EXEC SP_executeSQL @command
FETCH NEXT FROM Dev INTO  @DB
END
CLOSE Dev
DEALLOCATE Dev
GO
```

**

Would very much appreciate.

Comment: Were you able to come up with the improvement you wanted using the system views?

Answer (score 1):

Your script is assigning the user to the db_owner role.

All other permissions being applied are therefore redundant as this implies ALL of those other permissions.

[image]

Comment: you  are correct regarding the DB_Owner permission  as this a Dev box i wanted them to have the necessary permissions. I have not posted it but there 's another part of the script that's  assigning a service account as  the DB owner.
I was mainly interested on how to iterate through all the Schemas and assigning permissions as a whole,  instead of granting permissions  for each schemas individually.

Comment: Be aware that Database Owner and the db_owner role are different things.  Also, if you are going to iterate through all the schemas and grant the same permissions to each of them then why not apply them at the database level instead in one command?  Note also that the other roles are also a set of the individual permissions that your script applies.   Doubling up like this is an easy way to leave permissions in place when you think you are removing them.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to list all user schemas of a database, I think you should use [Schemas Catalog Views - sys.schemas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/schemas-catalog-views-sys-schemas?view=sql-server-ver15) or [SCHEMATA (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/schemata-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on your solution.

Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @command nvarchar(max) = N'';
DECLARE @user sysname = 'Domain\Development';

SELECT @command = @command + 'USE ' + DB_NAME() + '; 
    GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[' + name + '] TO [' + @user + '];
    GRANT DELETE ON SCHEMA::[' + name + '] TO [' + @user + '];
    GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA::[' + name + '] TO [' + @user + '];
    GRANT UPDATE ON SCHEMA::[' + name + '] TO [' + @user + '];
    GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[' + name + '] TO [' + @user + '];'
FROM sys.schemas
WHERE schema_id BETWEEN 5 AND 10000; --this should select only user created schemas

PRINT @command;
```

That's not a complete solution, but an example of how you could benefit from using one of the system views to achieve what you want.

Please, notice that I'm not considering what privileges are appropriate for the users on your environment, I'm just showing ways of listing the schemas without having to hardcode them as you mentioned.